# Will SqlClient or ADODB work if SQL Server is placed on a centralized server in network?

Tags: sql-server, database, connection, database-connection, adodb

The scenario is that I will be placing database on a centralized server and all the clients will have front ends accessing it, as I am connecting the front end and the back end I run into the question of whether using ADODB or SQLClient as my connection driver. I had preferred SQL Client these days, but I am not sure whether it will work if the SQL Server is placed on a centralized server?